# Passing scope variable to nested controller with template expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, controllers

So first of all a simple introduction to what I am trying to accomplish. I have my firstController initiated by ui-router. This controller serves me some page based data, in this specific case its a product list.

The firstController contains $scope.ids, which is an array of product id's. It initates secondController, which serves as the model and view of the productlist. The secondController handles features like filtering, sorting and so fourth, the firstController is the page itself.

The thirdController is the actual product controller. It is run for every product, and checks up on variants, special discounts and offers and so fourth.

My problem: The data-attr-id="{{ids}}" is not evaluated before the thirdController is initiated, thus the controller reads the data-attr-id value as {{ids}} instead if the array of numbers when the expression is evaluated.

I would prefer not to convert these into directives. Any suggestions?

```
<div ng-controller="firstController">

    <div ng-controller="secondController" data-attr-id="{{ids}}">

        <div ng-controller="thirdController" ng-repeat="product in productlist"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is data-attr-id?

Comment: data-attr-id is the array of products to list. In the secondController I call the productlist service, which returns an array of products. I pluck the id¨s out of that array and add it to a new array $scope.ids - which the productcontroller (thirdController) should use to loop through to call the actual products to get specifics

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand from your last comment why you are using three controllers so I've made a simpler example to help us to come to the right solution - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQHG5wUwDAymbBPaqYWq?p=preview).

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('firstController', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch("products", function(newValue) {
    if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
      $scope.ids = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
        $scope.ids += newValue[i].id + ", ";
      }
    }
  })
});

app.controller('secondController', function($scope) {
  $scope.getProducts = function() {
    $scope.products = [
      {id: "1", name: "product1"},
      {id: "2", name: "product2"},
      {id: "3", name: "product3"},
      {id: "4", name: "product4"},
      {id: "5", name: "product5"}
    ];
    $scope.$parent.products = $scope.products;
  }
});

app.controller('thirdController', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch("$parent.products", function(newValue) {
    if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
      $scope.productList = newValue;
    }
  })
});
```

Markup

```
  <div ng-controller="firstController">
    IDs: {{ids}}
    <div ng-controller="secondController">
        <button ng-click="getProducts()">Get products</button>
        <div ng-controller="thirdController">
          <div ng-repeat="product in productList">
            {{product.name}}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that is not what I am looking for. It is a bit more complex.

First of, the collection is a product list loaded through an angular service. When this service is loaded I will pluck the id's from the collection and add it in the frontend as an expression {{ids}}.

Comment: I add it to the data-attr-id attribute, as this is now the array of ids, which I want to make a specific entity selection from after in the thirdController.

The problem is that the thirdController is fired before the collection service has loaded, thus the data-attr-id is not evaluated in the frontend, and thirdController has is being served with {{ids}} instead of an array of product ids

Comment: I'am considering using a broadcast on the callback of the first service.

Comment: @mrbrandbart I've updated my answer to provide more help but I suspect it doesn't address what you are exactly trying to do. I'm happy to continue helping in anyway though.

Comment: @mrbrandbart The function in secondController is just to mimic a service.

Comment: yea I could tell, however the thing is that the secondController, with a static collection you'll get the result in time, but with an actual service the thirdController will have fired, and the data-attr-ids wont be evaluated in time.

I can see that you excluded the actual data-attributes in this example, which isn't the solution I am looking for. It requires the controllers to be tied together with the $parent, which is not ideal for our framework unfortunately, at least not if we can avoid it.

Comment: @mrbrandbart Sorry I couldn't help. I actually would have done the whole thing with directives but you stated that you didn't want to use them so I thought I'd have a go with just controllers. It's nice to take up the challenge.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort. We're looking into switching to dependencies, it's what makes sense, yet it gives a whole new set of issues.

Could be solved with $watch aswell, I just really want to avoid using $watch in this case.